# How to Autowire Spring Bean for Enum in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

**How can I avoid creating new objects by using spring configuration @Bean for Enums**

Example in below enum **E** how can I avoid **new A()** and **new B()** object creation using spring configuration Beans.

```
public enum E {

    FIRST(new A()),     // How to avoid creating new objects using Spring beans
    SECOND(new B());    

    private final I i;

    E(I arg){
        this.i = arg;
    }

    public static someMethod(){};
}
```

```
public interface I{
    int method(){}
}
```

```
public class A implements I {

    @Override
    public int method(){}
}

public class B implements I {

    @Override
    public int method(){}
}
```

Comment: i really dont understand what you are trying to achieve but you can't make enum into a bean if that is what you are after - enums have private constructor in Java (you can't change that) and Spring won't be able to instantiate something with private constructor.

Comment: I want to use a configuration with spring @Bean. I am looking for ways to avoid creating a new object everytime.

Comment: enums DO NOT create new object every time - they are by their definition singletons. Actually one of the simplest ways of making a singleton in Java is using an enum. 

Additionally every bean you create with `@Bean` or `@Component` will by default be a singleton so nothing special needs to be done. You just can't use enums to be instantiated by Spring

Comment: Correct. But it won't be managed by spring boot container. I am trying to make it optimal.

Comment: word optimal makes no sense in this context - did you mean to say optional? The way you formulated your question is very confusing. You are saying it wont be managed by Spring Container by you want to use `@Bean` which is the way you define beans for spring container to manage? That makes no sense

Comment: Hi @zeus - did you find any solution for this? I am also trying to achieve a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it in the following way.

```
public enum E {

    FIRST(SpringContext.getBean(A.class)),     // How to avoid creating new objects using Spring beans
    SECOND(SpringContext.getBean(B.class));

    private final I i;
    
    <T extends Object> BulkUploadType(T bean) {
        this.i = (I) bean;
    }

    E(I arg){
        this.i = arg;
    }

    public static someMethod(){};
}
```

The getBean method will return you the Bean of the implemented class.

```
public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanClass);
    }
```